# pdf of transformed random variable $g(X)$ as integral over $X$?

Tags: probability, transformation, dirac-delta

I am not a mathematician, so I am sorry if this question is too easy or some notational detail is not correct. I am trying my best!

I have got a random Variable $X$ in $\mathbb{R}^N$ with pdf $p(X)$ and a continuous, smooth function $g:\mathbb{R}^N \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$. I am interested in finding the pdf of $Y=g(X)$ (that is the probability of a point $x$ with $g(x)=y$) but as an integral over $X$.

I think the solution should look like

$$
p(Y=y) = \int_{\mathbb{R}^n} \delta(g(x)-y) p(X=x) \, dx \enspace,
$$

where $\delta(x)$ is the dirac-delta function.

But I can not proof it and i do not know of any easy to understand reference. Does someone here have any hint?

Comment: There is no easy and universal way to calculate pdf of $g(X)$. One way to approach is to calculate the cdf of $g(X)$: $F(y)=P(g(X)\leq y)$ and try from there to see the pdf. But if you want to calculate the expectation of $g(X)$, it is just $\int g(x) p(x)\mathrm{d}x$.

Comment: Hi, I am not searching for a closed-form solution of $g(X)$ as in my case i do not even know $p$. I want to apply another result for which i need to write the distribution of Y as some expectation over $p(x)$. In the discrete case, this is easy as we can just sum over the probabilities of all $x$ for which $g(x)=y$, but the continuous case is more complicated, because we integrate over a set with volume 0 (e.g. an elementary shell of a sphere).

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand your comment. It is impossible to have a universal expression of the pdf of $g(X)$, not only its closed form. So if you know what $g$ is, it is possible to proceed further by considering what $(g\leq y)$ is. This is essentially the same method as the discrete case. I'm not sure what kind of application you need. For applications, it may not be necessary to have an expression for the pdf of $g(X)$.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_delta_function#Composition_with_a_function

gives
$\int p(x) \delta(g(x)-y)dx= \int_{g^{-1}(y)} \frac{p(x)}{|\nabla g(x)|}d\sigma(x)$

and should be valid under the conditions of g i have given above. The right hand side indicates that we are integrating over the probabilities of all states for which g(x) maps to y. the only issue is that i do not know how the measure $d\sigma(x)$ is exactly affecting the evaluation the integral.

Comment: I think the only thing required is the right change of variable theorem, since i only need that
$E_{p(X=x)}\left\{ \delta(g(x)-y)\right\}=E_{p(Y=y')}\left\{ \delta(y'-y)\right\}=p(Y=y)$. Last step is given by the properties of the dirac-delta. This holds in all "easy" cases and so it would be sufficient for me if someone could point to a suitable generalization of the theorem.

Comment: One should not use the same symbol to refer both to the random variable and to the argument to its density function.  Thus one can write $\displaystyle \Pr(X\in A) = \int_A p(x)\,dx$ where $p$ is the density function of $X$, with capital $X$ as the random variable and lower-case $x$ as the argument to the density function. To confound the two would make an expression like $\Pr(X\le x)$ incomprehensible. $\qquad$